# How to change the font of a selection in powerpoint 2013 with VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint-2013

I would like to to change for the text selection in powerpoint 2013 the font to be bold and "Couirier New". I tried with this VBA script to change the font:

```
Sub chengeFont()
    With ActiveDocument.Selection
        With .Font
            .Name = "Courier New"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

but it is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: i m not sure but i think it is like selection.style.fontfamily= "Courier New" .fontstyle=Bold or font.bold=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will change the font and make it bold when you run it

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font
    .Name = "Courier New"
    .Bold = msoTrue
End With
```

Since you are running it from a selection the document will should always be the active one, other wise you will need to change the `ActiveWindow`

Comment: This doesn't work for text within SmartArt graphics, any idea how to get around that?